Click-to-Navigate while editing questions
When editing long questions, it would be helpful to be able to click on the render answer and have the cursor appear in the corresponding place in the editing text box to ease searching. Are there any plans of improving the editing field?
Syntax highlighting might be another good idea, I noticed it was not enabled (but it was asked here already).
